# Мultidimensional Аrrays as an argument for method

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

I wrote a method, that takes a multidimensional array as a parameter and returns the largest numbers of each:

```
static double[] FindLargest( double[][] NumsInNums ) {
    double[] Larges = new double[] {};
    int i = 0;

    foreach( double[] Nums in NumsInNums ) {
       Larges[i] = Nums.Max();
       i++;
    }

    return Larges;
}
```

But when i call it:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double[] nums = FindLargest( {{4, 2, 7, 1}, {20, 70, 40, 90}, {1, 2, 0}} );

    foreach(double num in nums) {
        Console.WriteLine(num);
    }
}
```

But this error appers:

[image]

What is wrong here?

Comment: It's just the wrong syntax for constructing an array. You'll need to use the appropriate array construction syntax

Comment: That's a "jagged array", not a "multidimensional array" which looks like "`double[,]`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems. Firstly your array declaration has an invalid syntax. It should be like this:

```
var nums = FindLargest( 
    new []
    {
        new double[] { 4, 2, 7, 1}, 
        new double[] { 20, 70, 40, 90},
        new double[] { 1, 2, 0}
    });
```

(I think that was probably OK in your actual code, because you seem to be asking about a different problem; see below!)

Secondly, in your `FindLargest()` method you are creating your result array, `Larges` with a size of zero. You need to create it with the correct size to accommodate all the results - in this case, it must be the same size as the `NumsInNums` array, which you can find via `NumInNums.Length`:

```
static double[] FindLargest(double[][] NumsInNums)
{
    double[] Larges = new double[NumsInNums.Length];
    int      i      = 0;

    foreach (double[] Nums in NumsInNums)
    {
        Larges[i] = Nums.Max();
        i++;
    }

    return Larges;
}
```

Just for completeness, I should point out that you can use the Linq `Enumerable.Select()` to simplify the code like so:

```
static double[] FindLargest(double[][] NumsInNums)
{
    return NumsInNums.Select(array => array.Max()).ToArray();
}
```

The `.Select()` takes each element of `NumInNums` (each element is an array) and then calls `Enumerable.Max()` for it, then takes all the results and puts them in an array (via the `ToArray()`).

Comment: but 'Secondly' is not obligatory is it?

Comment: The "Secondly" part makes the program crash, so yes it is!